# Why my data can't successful convert to json property I defined

Tags: kotlin

I'm try to convert a sqs message to a self defined SQS event, the message in convertMessageFromSqsForEvent is valid and it have value, but the sqsEventProperties is null, what is the problem?

```
fun convertMessageFromSqsForEvent(message: Message): SQSEventProperties? {
        var sqsEventProperties: SQSEventProperties? = null
        sqsEventProperties = mapper?.readValue(message.body, SQSEventProperties::class.java)

        return sqsEventProperties
 }
```

```
data class SQSEventProperties(
    @JsonProperty("attributes") var attributes: String?,
    @JsonProperty("awsRegion") var awsRegion: String?,
    @JsonProperty("body") var body: String?,
    @JsonProperty("eventSource") var eventSource: String?,
    @JsonProperty("eventSourceARN") var eventSourceARN: String?,
    @JsonProperty("md5OfBody") var md5OfBody: String?,
    @JsonProperty("md5OfMessageAttributes") var md5OfMessageAttributes: String?,
    @JsonProperty("messageId") var messageId: String?,
    @JsonProperty("receiptHandle") var receiptHandle: String?,
)
```

message

```
{MessageId: 94995ca7-ee33-4109-aabf-23d375878140,
ReceiptHandle: AQEBf5kvP0RwvFtKPmZglRhxXAS7FKGxbUCazYXD0+HFq6hpQGri3KU8TZirGC9NEu86DZretaBi5oeFbzzkWnMoxwzZ68/m7FZLt8fxX0gCoL2CxJMy0JXClRTZI+O06Hwn+CZMb5LOAKkGffJUS48dfe5GERKAZGsnLK4vA2pODrxfv1vvC6CXTzejoA9Dw+kuo51F5S86iRzXjItjzRJDxcJp4xeXdjrWps4Wfx233G+x4KiP9t9yZ73L9ucDLzdguDwTee07KG5SdRgHDQWyXcc0IJNtAe/NDmkIhWhigHoZSQmVCVNQFBtcYuB6X2khB+oQZsLz0Vh1NLs3zQVuusBbMg6tpk94N28FUKCIugtwDxBRjIdJqfbUXEeL1PxXCBcb+Pn3vLH9NHKHEclxbg==,
MD5OfBody: de5da762733bf71530cdb2aba2892a65,
Body: Please send request for updated data,
Attributes: {},
MessageAttributes: {}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the field of the data class must be the same as the key of the Json data. You can modify your data class and try again.

```kotlin
data class SQSEventProperties(
    @JsonProperty("Attributes") var attributes: String?,
    @JsonProperty("AwsRegion") var awsRegion: String?,
    @JsonProperty("Body") var body: String?,
    @JsonProperty("EventSource") var eventSource: String?,
    @JsonProperty("EventSourceARN") var eventSourceARN: String?,
    @JsonProperty("Md5OfBody") var md5OfBody: String?,
    @JsonProperty("Md5OfMessageAttributes") var md5OfMessageAttributes: String?,
    @JsonProperty("MessageId") var messageId: String?,
    @JsonProperty("ReceiptHandle") var receiptHandle: String?,
)
```